# How to get exit status or completion message from an asynchronous gcloud sql export job?

Tags: sql, asynchronous, gcloud

I have a daily export task for pulling data from gcloud sql to a bucket in cloud storage, but the job winds up timing out and gcloud sends back an error saying this. Nonetheless, the SQL instance continues running the export, and the files make it to their destination, no problem.

In order to get around the timeout error, which is fouling up our logs, I have tried adding the --async flag, which gets around the error as it should, but there is no exit or completion message.

`gcloud --project=$PROJECT sql export csv cloud-sql --database=$DB $BUCKET/$(date +%Y%m%d)_$NAME.csv --async --query="`cat $SQLPATH/$table.sql`" >> $LOG 2>&1`

Is there some bash code or modification I can make to receive a status update or exit response to that I can accurately log that the job has been completed?

Comment: Does `--async` yield an operation? You should be able to block (or poll) the operation for status. Please file an issue on Google issuetracker for the synchronous command timing out before the export succeeds.

Comment: How can I check if an operation is yielded? My sense is that a request gets sent to the cloud, and the asynchonicity is happening there rather than client-side--my script just moves on to the next line, and I've confirmed the gcloud command exits with code 0, even though the job is busy being processed on the gcloud side.

Comment: See asbovelmw@ answer. There's also `gcloud sql operations wait ${OPERATION}` which would save you the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can start this bash code at the same time you issue the command in another process. It has a function that gets the status of the operation (whose id is saved in the log), then the first status read and the next ones are compared until they are different, and the status is printed periodically:

`OPERATION=$(cat $LOG|tr / \ | awk '{print $NF}'| tail -n 1)
get_status(){
    CURRENT_STATUS=$(gcloud sql operations describe $OPERATION | grep status: | awk '{print $NF}')
}
FIRST_STATUS=$CURRENT_STATUS
echo FIRST STATUS: $FIRST_STATUS
while [ $FIRST_STATUS == $CURRENT_STATUS ]
do
    get_status
echo CURRENT STATUS: $CURRENT_STATUS
sleep 5
done
echo CURRENT STATUS: $CURRENT_STATUS
echo DONE!`